# Applying for bachelors science program, should I include my high-school transcript or just post-secondary transcripts?

Tags: bachelor, transcript-of-records

I have graduated from a 2 year Computer Systems Technology diploma program at BCIT, and am applying for general sciences at UBC, with the intention of moving forward to get a combined bachelors in Computer Science and Statistics.  They advise submitting a high-school transcript, but it is not mandatory like my post-secondary transcripts are.  My high-school transcript is not flattering.  My grades from high-school were much worse than the grades I got in my time in the CST program at BCIT.  In high school there were a few classes that I came extremely close to failing (Physics 12, Chemistry 12, and precalc 12), and only 1 class I actually excelled in (Advanced Placement Computer Science). Would it look worse on me to submit a bad transcript, or no transcript at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a no brainer.  It's NOT REQUIRED and it DOESN'T LOOK GOOD.  Skip the high school transcript and just give them the juco transcript.